# How to decrease the zoom level of google-map loaded in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, iframe

I am loading map completely by iframe. In iframe all code corresponding to map is present. Iframe loaded dynamically in which zoom effect is not present. I want to control zoom effect of map in this case. I know if map is directly loaded then it can control by "z" factor in link. But if in iFrame all map code is present so how i control on zoom factor of the map.

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $file_name; ?>" width="100%" height="700px;" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

this is code of line and $file_name is the html file load dynamically.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70809/how-to-change-default-zoom-in-the-google-embedded-map

Comment: Can't you use the`z=x` where x is a number between 1 and 20 in your src URL?

Comment: @RiteshPaliwal. It would be great if you put your **code** on the question section instead of here, in the comment section itself.

Comment: What does your `$file_name` html document contain?

Comment: $file_name id the .html file and it contain all code corresponding to map and it comes dynamically so that we can't edit this file.we have to control zoom level at our own side.

Answer (score 0):

map.setZoom(zoom:number)

[Check this link for gmap options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of Z accordingly and the URL of course..

```
<iframe src="http://mapsengine.google.com/map/u/0/embed?mid=zYk_BmXXTdxw.k83snDbX5SJc&z=9" width="745" height="480"></iframe>
```

[Check this for more info](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70809/how-to-change-default-zoom-in-the-google-embedded-map)

Comment: and what are you trying to achieve here? what are you using? need to be specific.